# Bin packing with given bin sizes, not necessarily same

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

I was thinking about variants of bin packing and thought of this variant wherein the given $m$ bins have size specified(not necessarily same) and we need to put $n$ objects in them. Is this still NP Hard, considering that bin packing is NP hard?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's still **NP**-hard, because the input could specify that the bins actually are the same size, which is the standard **NP**-hard version.

A general rule of thumb is that allowing the input to be more general can't make the problem any easier, as long as the new setting includes the original hard case as a special case.